# Pushing my code onto DotCloud from cloud9ide.com

Tags: git, github, dotcloud

I'm coding on the [cloud9ide](http://cloud9ide.com/), which pushes to [github](https://github.com). I then host it on [dotcloud](http://www.dotcloud.com/). I'm trying to see if there's some way I can get my code to deploy onto [dotcloud](/questions/tagged/dotcloud) when I push on [cloud9ide](/questions/tagged/cloud9ide) without doing the extra round of pulling it to my local computer, and running their command line tool.

Right now my workflow is this:

```
cloud9ide -> github

$ git pull
github -> local

$ dotcloud push project.www .
local -> dotcloud
```

Is there some way I can skip the last step and auto push it to dotcloud? Reading their [documentation suggests](http://docs.dotcloud.com/faq/#can-i-git-push-my-code-to-dotcloud) I can't directly push to them via [git](/questions/tagged/git).

Answer (score 4):

Technically, you *could* git push directly to DotCloud (that's what the DotCloud CLI does behind the scenes); but you still would have to carry a few extra steps to trigger the build process (it's not triggered by the git push itself).

A better approach might be to setup a post-receive hook on github. The hook would signal a small and lean service somewhere (maybe on DotCloud itself). This service would then refresh its local git repository, and schedule a `dotcloud push`.

In the long term, DotCloud will probably provide a more streamlined integration with github; but meanwhile, this could do the trick with minimal effort.

Answer (score 0):

Couple of points:

1. Maybe it is just me but I don't see any merit in deploying on production on every commit / push.
2. This is bit of a hack but you should be able to listen to a Git repository and run the DotCloud CLI push command using a continuous integration software such as Jenkins (formerly known as Hudson) etc.